# looping and executing dynamic query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having some trouble truncating some tables that get generated in my base.
The table names get saved and I can do it manually, but I wanted to see if it could be automated until its fixed.

What I've done so far is get all the table names and a id/number into my own help table. My errors begin around the loop/Execute immediate where im not sure how to use the data I've gotten in the syntax and i cant find any similar examples.

```
create table HlpTruncTable as SELECT SUBSTR(argument, 3) as tblName, rownum as Nr 
FROM tblLogHlp
WHERE status = 'E' and argument like '0,awfh%' and LAST_UPDATE <= ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-1);

for i in 1..(select max(nr) from HlpTruncTable) LOOP   
     execute immediate TRUNCATE TABLE (select tblName from HlpTruncTable where nr = (i));    
END LOOP;

drop table hlpTruncTable;
```

Comment: It seems that you are using a `for` loop (PLSQL) in SQL; have a look at anynomous blocks, procedures, packages. Besides, `execute immediate` needs a string. An hint: start building a procedure that loops through your tables and simply prints their names; when this will work, adding the `execute` will be easy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
declare

cursor HlpTruncTable is 
SELECT SUBSTR(argument, 3) as tblName
FROM tblLogHlp
WHERE status = 'E' and argument like '0,awfh%' and LAST_UPDATE <= ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-1);

BEGIN
   FOR aTable IN HlpTruncTable LOOP
      execute immediate 'TRUNCATE TABLE '||aTable.tblName;
   END LOOP;
END;
```